# I am getting this error of Firebase auth but error is not going to solve in any way

Tags: android, quickblox, q-municate

I modified Q-municate powered by QuickBlox (which is open source) GitHub code and I put my own credentials to Firebase authentication but I am getting this error. I put all credentials, but still, I do not know what the error is.

I put all these credentials but it's still giving an error and also mentioned in the image about the error.

```
Project ID: 
APP ID:     
Package name:
```

These things I put in the project. Can anybody tell what the error mentioned in image is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In current version of Q-municate (2.5) you need just add new parameter `devFirebaseAuthProjectId=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"` to file  q-municate-android/Q-municate_app/gradle.properties. Value for this parameter you can get in Firebase Developer Console, see screenshot: [image: screenshot] Additionally check SHA1 for your debug key in Firebase Developer Console.

Comment: Unfortunately, Still verification is not going successfully after doing this step.